# Retrieve all Adjacent Nodes where Nodes are specific type and at least one is NOT subject of specific triple

Tags: sparql

I have a SPARQL query designed to retrieve all instances of a specific class which are adjacent to an instance of another specific class. For example:

```sql
SELECT ?origin ?dependent WHERE {
  ?origin a :type1 . 
  ?origin ?somePredicate ?dependent. 
  ?dependent a :type2 .
}
```

Let's say the results from the above query look like this:

```
?origin    ?dependent
node1      node3
node1      node4
node2      node5
node2      node6
```

So in this case, there are two nodes of the specified type connected to both `node1` and `node2`. Now, I would like to restrict the results to just those `?dependent` results where at least one of those two nodes is NOT the subject of a specific triple, but still return both in the case that only one of them has the triple.

Let's say the following triples exist in the graph:

```
node4 :isSubjectOf :thisTriple .
node5 :isSubjectOf :thisTriple .
node6 :isSubjectOf :thisTriple .
```

Let's assume that `node3` is the only one of nodes 3-6 which DOES NOT have this specific triple. Now, I want to write a query to have my resultset look like this:

```
?origin    ?dependent
node1      node3
node1      node4
```

I hope I phrased this question well enough to be understood. Is there some convenient and efficient SPARQL technique to accomplish something like this? Would prefer to avoid `FILTER` if possible.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223

Comment: @StanislavKralin you are right, in retrospect I should have asked another question rather than updating my previous question. I found a solution for this problem which is specific to my application, but have not thought of a general solution which would be appropriate to qualify as an accepted answer here.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I envision your data:

```
@prefix ns0: <http://example.com/> .

<http://example.com/node1>
  a <http://example.com/type1> ;
  ns0:somePredicate ns0:node3, ns0:node4 .

ns0:node2
  a ns0:type1 ;
  ns0:somePredicate ns0:node5, ns0:node6 .

ns0:node3
  a ns0:type2 ;
  ns0:isSubjectOf ns0:thisTriple .

ns0:node4 a ns0:type2 .
ns0:node5 a ns0:type2 .
ns0:node6 a ns0:type2 .
```

And this is a query that gets what you asked for.  You can create different triple patterns between the same subject and same object as long as you use a different variable name for the predicate binding them.

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.com/>

SELECT  ?origin ?dependent
WHERE
  { ?origin   a                     :type1 ;
              ?somePredicate        ?dependent .
    ?dependent  a                   :type2 .
    ?origin   ?anyPred              ?theSubj .
    ?theSubj  :isSubjectOf          ?theTrip
  }
```

And the result:

```
+--------+-----------+
| origin | dependent |
+--------+-----------+
| :node1 | :node3    |
| :node1 | :node4    |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: This answer is great for my previous question. I updated the question to better reflect my actual use case, which is to include only in the ABSENCE of a specific triple, not the presence of one.

Comment: I think you could do this negative case with either a `MINUS` operation, or with the dreaded `FILTER(!bound(?theTrip))` or `FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?theSubj  :isSubjectOf ?theTrip }`

Comment: I think that these solutions would not return a resultset including the case of one dependent with the triple and one without

Comment: @hayfreed It would be good if you provide a full minimal sample of the data such that we don't have to guess and create the data by ourselves. And this data should be a valid RDF snippet such that one can run and test SPARQL queries on it

Comment: There are so many options to solve your problem. Don't forget that you can also put a `UNION` into the `FILTER NOT EXISTS``and that SPARQL 1.1 also provides `IF-ELSE` feature